# OTG Android Wifi dongle

Tags: wi-fi, usb-on-the-go

**I need your advice.**

I have a Nexus 5x.
I'd like to connect Wifi dongle with Nexus 5x to use larger antenna for wifi.
[Example product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J65G9DD)

**[Nexus 5x]--[Otg cable]--[USB wifi product]**

I tested with a [usb-wifi module](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B071DRF9FN).

[image]

My nexus 5x recognize my usb-wifi device as "Ralink 802.11 n WLAN".
I used "[Easy Otg Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kjarvel.easyotgchecker&hl=ja)" app to check device name.

but. I do not have confident whether Nexus can use dongle as wifi.
Is there any way to use wifi dongle on Android smartphone ?

I saw [a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EbYqLFqo60&t=235s). but I do not know...How to...

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: No. it is not rooted.  Should I do rooted ?

Comment: With root access you can manually create and configure network interface. The problematic part is if kernel doesn't have driver for the dongle, which is not your case.